# How to get text from drop-down button using Selenium?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

There is a webpage with drop-down button with text inside. I want to retrieve text from that drop-down button, which is : "Description text".

Here is html code part:

```html
<div data-v-e0a13c66="" data-v-5e9bf2df="" id="DetailDescription" class="detail-dropdown">
    <header data-v-e0a13c66="" class="detail-dropdown__header">
        <h5 data-v-e0a13c66="" class="detail-dropdown__title detail-dropdown__title--open">Описание</h5>
        <svg data-v-e0a13c66="" width="8" height="14"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="detail-dropdown__arrow--open detail-dropdown__arrow">
            <path data-v-e0a13c66="" d="M5.38 6.978c-.03-.02-.065-.036-.09-.06A10051.03 10051.03 0 0 1 .544 2.17C.202 1.83.154 1.335.424.962A.916.916 0 0 1 1.765.807c.032.027.061.057.091.087l5.42 5.42c.41.41.41.96 0 1.37L1.831 13.13c-.401.4-1.018.38-1.373-.046a.918.918 0 0 1 0-1.164c.033-.04.07-.078.108-.115L5.29 7.08c.025-.025.06-.04.09-.06v-.043Z"></path>
        </svg>
    </header>
    <div data-v-e0a13c66="" class="detail-dropdown__body">
        <article data-v-37bed4a0="" data-v-e0a13c66="" itemprop="description" class="detail-desc">
            <p data-v-37bed4a0="" class="detail-desc__text detail-desc__text--main">
                <p>Description text.</p>                <!---->                <!----></article>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but when i run this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def web_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--verbose")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920, 1200")
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    return driver


description_tags = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@*[contains(., 'detail-dropdown_body')]]")
list(map(lambda x: x.text, description_tags))
```

but the output is empty. How could i fix it?

Comment: There's two underscores `detail-dropdown__body`

Comment: @Daviid same output

Comment: update the code in the question with what you currently have.

Comment: The HTML is missing a closing `</p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

To get your element by XPATH you should use

```js
description_tags = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'detail-dropdown__body')]")
```

`.` literal in xpath contains searches for text, but actually you need to search for `class`, so instead `.` you should use `@class`.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text ***Description text.*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.detail-dropdown__body > article.detail-desc p"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='detail-dropdown__body']/article[@class='detail-desc']//p[text()]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)